# Terminal modified permanently by vscode

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

I installed vscode today and followed the steps on tutorials on youtube to set up. My terminal started to act weird after I called python through the terminal and tried to use `pip install` command but failed. I uninstalled the app, deleted all the relevant files, and tried to reopen the terminal. The terminal still has the same warnings.

I have contacted Apple Tech support and they say my terminal got modified by the app. They asked me to contact the app developer.

I don't know what I did to get where I am now. I would appreciate any help that can bring my terminal back to normal.

Below are the warnings even after I uninstalled the app:

```
Last login: Wed Jun 10 23:02:45 on ttys000
You have mail.
-bash: Saving: command not found
-bash: ...copying: command not found
-bash: ...saving: command not found
-bash: ...completed.: command not found
-bash: Deleting: command not found

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
ZhouChristinas-MacBook-Pro:~ zhouchristina$
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, John. I found this page on github https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md and it directed me to here to ask questions. I will ask this question in the communities you mentioned.

Comment: I see. Yeah, that's a common problem: some third party software or company says "go to Stack Overflow for support" and then when folks come here their questions get downvoted and/or closed. The problem is Stack Overflow isn't an official support resource. We've got our own rules and policies that don't always line up well with the third parties'. I apologize for the disconnect because it's not really your fault, you're just caught in the middle.

Comment: Still, I was wrong to say that your question is off-topic. VSCode is a programming tool so asking questions about it is fine here. We just may not be the best equipped to help if it turns out to be a macOS issue. If you don't get a good answer you could also ask at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! And no worries! I'm new to the community and I appreciate someone who could give me some guidance. :) Look forward to future engagement here.

Comment: Did this ever get solved? I have [the same problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465930/apple-terminal-startup-errors-session-save-restore) as @ScottMarks below, and am trying to figure out if it's really the same as this (and if so, how to fix it)...

Answer (score 2):

```
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-I[date|hours|minutes|seconds]] [-f input_fmt]
            [-r filename|seconds] [-v[+|-]val[y|m|w|d|H|M|S]]
            [[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.SS] | new_date] [+output_fmt]
-bash: Saving: command not found
```

In my case this was caused by `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` not handling asynchronous shutdown of Terminal windows.  Here's the `diff` of the change I made that fixed it for me (YMMV):

```
scott@Mac-mini-x86 etc $ diff  bashrc_Apple_Terminal.orig bashrc_Apple_Terminal 
215,219c215,223
<       echo -ne '\nSaving session...' >&2
<       (umask 077; echo 'echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r '$(/bin/date +%s)')"' >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE")
<       declare -F shell_session_save_user_state >/dev/null && shell_session_save_user_state
<       shell_session_history_allowed && shell_session_save_history
<       echo 'completed.' >&2
---
>       local save_lock_file="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/_saving_lockfile"
>       if /usr/bin/shlock -f "${save_lock_file}" -p $$; then
>           (umask 077; echo 'echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r '$(/bin/date +%s)')"' >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE")
>           echo -ne '\nSaving session...' >&2
>           declare -F shell_session_save_user_state >/dev/null && shell_session_save_user_state
>           shell_session_history_allowed && shell_session_save_history
>           echo 'completed.' >&2
>           /bin/rm "${save_lock_file}"
>       fi
```

Comment: Aha, am I *not* [the only person seeing this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465930/apple-terminal-startup-errors-session-save-restore?noredirect=1#comment689471_465930)? So at least there are two of us, but are there more?

Comment: (Do you think it is generic, but not everyone is noticing it? Or is there something unique about our systems? Note that I sometimes also get what I think is output from the `printf` statement that appears in `update_terminal_cwd()` saved into `$SHELL_SESSION_FILE`, which is even weirder.)

Comment: As I noted elsewhere, I don't think this has anything to do with VSCode.  I think it's an Apple bug.

Comment: I'm no longer sure that it's multiple Terminal sessions, although it is definitely a race condition writing the history file.  But the most significant development to watch for is that ANY MACOS UPDATE will overwrite `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`  back to its buggy state from whatever fix you may have made!  Boo!  C'mon Apple!  It's a small, safe fix!

Comment: Also note, not obvious and perhaps lost in the posting, is that the patched area is TAB-indented, so if you just copy/paste the patch, fix the lines with initial 8+ spaces to start with a TAB instead.

Answer (score -1):

Check your shell's startup script, it looks like you have text there that aren't shell commands. I don't know whether you have bash or zsh as your shell, but check all of these files just to be sure:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_aliases
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.zshrc
~/.zshenv
~/.zprofile
~/.zlogin
~/.profile
```

Also look into any files that are [sourced](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) by these files.

Comment: "Permission denied" for ~/.bash_profile, and all other commands are "No such file or directory". What should I look for?